# React Native - Trying to print depending on the state of index

Tags: react-native

I am trying to loop through this array and print out the quote, depending on if it is saved as true or false. 
At the moment, it just prints out in the JSON array. I'm new to react native, so not 100% certain of the behaviour of `map`.

```
var savedQuote = quotes.quotesArray.map(quote => quote.isSaved) 

{
                  quotes.quotesArray.map((quote, i) => {
                    if(savedQuote){
                        return(                            
                            <TouchableOpacity key={i} style = {styles.border}>
                              <Text style = {styles.text}>
                                i: {i}. {quotes.quotesArray[i].preview}
                              </Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity> 
                        )
                    }
                    else{
                        return <Text key = {i}>{i}Nada</Text>
                    }
                  })
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you have two `map` in your code. One should suffice :

```
quotes.quotesArray.map((quote, i) => {
  if(quote.isSaved){
    return(                            
      <TouchableOpacity key={i} style = {styles.border}>
        <Text style = {styles.text}>
          i: {i}. {quote.preview}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity> 
    )
  } else {
    return <Text key = {i}>{i}Nada</Text>
  }
});
```

This will loop through quotes and either return one node or the either if quote.isSaved is true or not.

you could save them to a new array if you assign it to a new variable ex: `var savedQuotes = ...` or use it inside your render function :

```
   render() {
     return (
       <View>
        {quotes.quotesArray.map...}
      </View>
     );
   }
```

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in this array.

Here is more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Here are some examples from the react documentation : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html (which should be close enough to react-native)

Comment: this doesn't have the variable "i". Does i need to be after quote?

Comment: Sorry ! My bad. I edited my answer. the second parameter is optional, unless you use it of course...

Comment: I made a second edit... ```quote``` represents the element you are iterating on, therefore, you don't need ```quotes.quotesArray[i].preview``` but rather ```quote.preview```

Comment: this returns `A valid react element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object. ` - Not sure why.

Comment: I am not sure... I works it you surround by a ```<View>``` tag

Comment: The problem, if you don't wrap the map with a tag, is that it will return sibling elements. And in react, you can only return one node to ```React.createElement()```, which is used behind the scene by React Native